# async / await not working

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous

I have written a sample .net win forms application to learn
async/await concept.

My sample win form has 2 buttons[button1,button2] ,and below 
are the click event handlers for both.

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
  string str = await BL.LongRunningOperation();
  MessageBox.Show(str); 
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  MessageBox.Show("Any Time");
}
```

Below is the long running operation ,which gets invoked on click event
of button1

```
public class BL
{

    public  static async Task<string> LongRunningOperation()
    {
        string strReturnValue = "Long Running Operation";

        int i = 0;

        while (i <= 1000000000)
        {
            i++;
        }

        return strReturnValue;
    }
}
```

My assumption was once the user clicks the Button1 , the long running
operation will get executed asynchronously, and in the mean time user
can click button2.

But what I observed is that,user is able to click button2 only once
long running operation gets completed.

Please let me know what needs to be modifed to make this call async.

Comment: await does not start anything. It waits for something that is already running.

Comment: The answers are good enough; however, the compiler warned you about the code not being asynchronous before you ever even executed your application. This is why you must pay attention to compilation warnings!

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/03/24/10287244.aspx

Comment: @Jonathan Dickinson , yep , I will , from next time

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your `LongRunningOperation` doesn't actually do anything asynchronously, so it won't run on another thread and return to the click handler. There should have been a compiler warning about this as your `async` method doesn't have an `await` in it.

As suggested by other answers, write your click handler like this:

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
  string str = await Task.Run(() => BL.LongRunningOperation());
  MessageBox.Show(str); 
}
```

Comment: Add an example demonstrating how to fix, e.g. `await Task.StartNew(BL.LongRunningOperation)`.

Comment: @Sean , As Jonathan Dickinson suggested , can you please add an example.

Comment: @CleanCrispCode in addition to the example, there is no need for `async Task<>` on LongRunningOperation - the method itself is not async (async methods will have `await` in their implementation).

Answer (score 3):

As is your example is executing synchronously so you might try wrapping your long running operation body in a

```
public static async Task<string> LongRunningOperation()
{
    return await Task.Run(()=>
    {
        string strReturnValue = "Long Running Operation";

        int i = 0;

        while (i <= 1000000000)
        {
            i++;
        }

        return strReturnValue;
    });
}
```